# Plotting 100 or more pins on Google maps

Tags: iphone, cocoa, google-maps, ios7, gmsmapview

In a Google map i want to plot 100 or more pins at a time, Now i am plotting all pins manually using for loop & it is taking more time. Is it possible to plot all pins at once

```
  for (KZObject *flt in arrayList){
 GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = r1;
        marker.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",flt.cvId];
        marker.appearAnimation = YES;
                marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotationIcon_p"];
 marker.map = self.mapview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{"zoom":17,"tilt":0,"mapTypeId":"roadmap","center":{"lat":51.48258734258928000,"lng":-3.15550769507571800},"overlays":
[
{"type":"marker","title":"","content":"","position":{"lat":51.48258734258928000,"lng":-3.15550769507571800}},
{"type":"marker","title":"","content":"","position":{"lat":51.48341717170673000,"lng":-3.15433334291887800}},
{"type":"marker","title":"","content":"","position":{"lat":51.48240026213740000,"lng":-3.15533015030956900}},
{"type":"marker","title":"","content":"","position":{"lat":51.48316744527602000,"lng":-3.15412541474515500}},
{"type":"marker","title":"","content":"","position":{"lat":51.48265396827342000,"lng":-3.15147700313981100}},
{"type":"marker","title":"","content":"","position":{"lat":51.48182419769601000,"lng":-3.14990078269657700}}, 
{"type":"marker","title":"","content":"","position":{"lat":51.49180210780110000,"lng":-3.17291056975810400}}
]}
```

Try this

Source   [Blits Gmap Editor](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html)